# Remove Query Parameter from Laravel Scout Pagination Links()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel Scout to search for objects in my database, and need to have the results paginated, but Scout is automatically including a 'query' query term in the url in addition to the page number instead of just the page number.

I'm using the Scout built in pagination like so:
`$page_results = Page::search($validatedData['search_terms'])->paginate(10, 'page_results');`

The problem is that instead of just getting the page number as a query, I'm also getting another 'query' stuck in there as well:
`http://192.168.10.10/wiki/search?query=a&page_results=2`

As my route is like this:
`Route::post('/search', 'SearchController@search');`
Its not expecting that query and is sending it to the fallback.

Is there a way to remove the 'query' query from the Scout links()? What I would like ideally is the following as I've got pagination working on other pages just fine by using the Eloquent pagination which doesn't include that extra query term:
 `http://192.168.10.10/wiki/search?page_results=2`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think that's how the pagination works. you need to change the POST request to GET request in the route.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
$page_results->withPath('results');
```

[Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to remove `query` from query string by calling `->appends('query', null)` on your `->paginate()` method.

There is closed [issue](https://github.com/laravel/scout/issues/58) on github about this.